# Meteor helpers modify output

Tags: angularjs, meteor

I need some help with meteor.
I created a publish in the server side and after subscription in the client side I added a helper to get my data.

```
this.helpers({
      tags() {
        var tags = Tag.find();
        return tags;
      }
})
```

What I need to do is add a Key called Cheked = true to tags.
How can I do this please ? because if I do it in the init it will not work since the suscription is not ready yet.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [.map()](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-map) to map the cursor and add a key to each document:

```
this.helpers({
  tags() {
    let tags = Tag.find().map(doc=>{
      doc.checked = true;
      return doc;
    });
    return tags;
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much Michel this is exacty what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try with that way:

```
Template.myTemplateName.helpers({
 tags(){
   //You should use also find().fetch()
      return Tag.find().fetch();
 }
});
```

show your subs code.
If you want to add key to the object you should use

```
Tag.update(id,{$set: {keyName: value}}) on selected id or all elements.
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment But I don't want to change the values in the collection only in my controller so I don't want to use .update